# Undefined Constant with Many to Many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a many to many :through association in my rails application between 'User' and 'List' model objects.

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :username
  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :lists, :through => :user_lists                                          
end

#list.rb
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :users, through => :user_lists
  attr_accessible :description, :title
end

#userlist.rb
class UserList < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :list
end
```

In the console if I attempt to select all the lists (User.first.lists) from a user I get the following error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant User::UserList

I'm new to rails. I'm guessing I have something named wrong. Table names are as follows users, lists, user_lists

Can someone tell me what I have wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails magic will look for `UserList` in *app/models/user_list.rb*, not *app/models/userlist.rb*.